# Issue with watchOS app when submit iOS app

Tags: ios, swiftui, watchos

I have an issue when uploading iOS app with watchOS, when I upload the iOS app it's showing that there is no WatchOS app attached to it. I tested the app in the simulator and it is working fine, here is the targets for my app it is showing there are watchOS targets attached to it

[image: Project targets showing there are watchOS targets]

[image: here is the image showing app working fine in simulator]

every time I upload the iOS build it is showing there is no Apple Watch app attached. can anyone help me out to figure out what is the problem for this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could think this is it. Watch app for iOS is installed with the iOS app, stand-alone watch app is installed standalone via the watch app store

Comment: Yes thank you, I found it it looks like it is an independent watchOS app